# Creating a dropdown based on the List inside the bottomsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, bottom-sheet

In my code, I am parsing Json and creating a List of Maps, And for each Map, I want to display them in a dropdown.

**here is my code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReportFilter extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map jsonString;
  var globalData;

  ReportFilter({@required this.jsonString, this.globalData});

  @override
  _ReportFilterState createState() => _ReportFilterState();
}

class _ReportFilterState extends State<ReportFilter> {
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
  TextEditingController controller;
  Map<String, Object> globalValues = Map<String, Object>();

  String type;
  int optionId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    globalValues = widget.globalData;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: FlatButton.icon(
                label: Text('Filters'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                onPressed: () => showModalSheet(),
              )),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  showModalSheet() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> dropdownList = List<Map<String, Object>>();

       // here I am fetching data from json and doing some operations and storing the result into the List of maps, i.e dropdownList
// below I showed the contents of the dropdownList, and I am passing this list to the Dropdown menu. The contents of the list is dynamic and it keeps changing, It may contains any no of type value as String in  map, or List in map

    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter state) {
              return createBox(context, dropdownList, state);

          });
        });
  }

  createBox(BuildContext context, List<Map<String, Object>> val,
      StateSetter setState) {
    Widget supporting = buildSupportingWidget(val, setState);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: LimitedBox(
            maxHeight: 300,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildMainDropdown(val, setState),
                  if (supporting != null) supporting
                ])));
  }

  Expanded buildMainDropdown(
      List<Map<String, Object>> items, StateSetter setState) {
    return Expanded(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: type,
          hint: Text("Select a type"),
          items: items
              .map((json) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(json["displayName"]), value: json["type"]))
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (newType) {
            setState(() {
              type = newType;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSupportingWidget(
      List<Map<String, Object>> items, StateSetter setState) {
    if (type == "list") {
      List<Map<String, Object>> options = items[1]["data"];
      return Expanded(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            value: optionId,
            hint: Text("Select an entry"),
            items: options
                .map((option) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(option["displayId"]), value: option["id"]))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (newId) => setState(() {
              this.optionId = newId;
            }),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (type == "string") {
      return Expanded(child: TextFormField());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

In show model sheet I am doing some operations to get the List of Maps,
 So after executing those, my **`dropdownList`** List have data like this,

```
[
      {
        "displayName": "Enter value",
        "type": "string",
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Enter second value",
        "type": "string",
      },
      {
        "id": "si",
        "displayName": "Source",
        "type": "list",
        "value": ["MO"], "searchField": "si",
        "data": [
          {"id": 1, "displayId": "MO"},
          {"id": 2, "displayId": "AO"},
          {"id": 3, "displayId": "OffNet"}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

It can be multiple strings, or lists depend on the Json I am processing,

Then I am passing the  list to  create box there I am calling the Dropdown functions, but I am not getting how to create those dropdowns based on the List, and also managing the final data once the user selects the particular item,

like if the user in the first dropdown selects an item that needs a text box, I need to store that entered value somewhere, and also if he selects the list from the first dropdown which results in displaying the other dropdown, I need to Store both the data in somewhere. 
if someone has done something like this before, or someone knows this please let me know, Thank you

Comment: You can simplify your question with sharing only the related code(not extra code) and summarizing what you are aiming to. In that case people will be more likely to answer your question. Because both your code and explanation a little verbose according to complexity of what you want.

Comment: okay, I will edit the question then